# Random errors in decompressed files

Tags: server, files, gzip, unzip

I have a server with 14.04 installed. As I was using unzip and gzip I noticed a weird thing: the decompressed files were corrupted, meaning that random characters appeared in place of other characters inside the files. It's actually pretty weird and after searching I couldn't find anything about it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Gzip has error-detecting code, like if there's an error (ex. one changed byte) gzip will complain & tell you about it. Some archive formats like zip and 7z say if there's an error, I just tested gzip (changed one byte in a 3k .gz) and it complained: `gzip: test.gz: invalid compressed data--crc error`

Does gzip (gunzip) complain about any corruption while uncompressing, or are the files just silently messed up? If gzip doesn't complain then maybe they were messed up to start with when they were stored, and were successfully stored with the corruption.

Maybe storage medium/disk errors, or transmission/network/copying errors, or I've even seen bad ram that would give occasional random errors in the middle of files before. I'd try memtest, then some testing on the storage drive like fsck or badblocks, or did you make hashes to test for file errors, like crc32/md5/sha checksum files?